# Unable to find relevant linux headers

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, chrome-os, linux-headers

I am going through the steps to be able to use my Wacom tablet (CTL-6100WL) and I am to the point where I am installing the linux headers however this happens.

```
(xenial)grace@localhost:~$ uname -r
3.18.0-18720-g7b8c1dc67cda
(xenial)grace@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.18.0-18720-g7b8c1dc67cda
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-3.18.0-18720-g7b8c1dc67cda'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.18.0-18720-g7b8c1dc67cda'
```

When looking at how other people have done it and what their issues were, their kernal names were a lot smaller. I'm not sure if this is because I am using Linux on a Chromebook and that is making it difficult.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on top of ChromeOS (Crouton).

I'm using [these steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom/LatestDriver) on the Oracle website. It is at  [this point](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source) where I'm having issues with the first prerequisite stage for Ubuntu; the second line worked and I was able to complete steps after that except for building the driver since I don't have the Linux headers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right that this is difficult because its a Chromebook. Could you point us to the steps you're trying to proceed through? (E.g., a link to the instructions you found). Also, is your Chromebook in developer mode? If I remember correctly, you can't change the kernel/modules otherwise. Also, is this Crouton? Or some other way of installing Ubuntu? (Sorry, it's been a while since I touched a Chromebook — apologies if I'm asking for silly clarifications).

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but since you were able to get far enough to install, you obviously did everything right (developer mode set, write screw taken out of the back, flashed the bios, etc.).  What you need to do now is get a kernel that has the right modules compiled in it to work with your chromebook.  Either run gallium OS, or download the gallium OS kernel and replace your ubuntu kernel with it.  You could try forcing this one in, but if your goal is just linux on a chromebook, go with gallium OS :)

Comment: @derobert Yeah, I'll edit the post with links to the various sites I'm using. My Chromebook is in developer mode and you're right, it is on Crouton. No silly clarifications as I was unsure of which information I needed to provide in the first place!